# Identifying the callback to a SFRestRequest delegate

Tags: rest-api, sfrestrequest

Is it possible and safe to set the SFNetworkOperation tag in the method initiating the request, and then read it back in the delegate method, to distinguish which request was made? Or is there a better way? I've considered creating a delegate for every call. I'd prefer not to use blocks. I've also seen solutions that (when using custom apex) wrap the return data in a json wrapper with an identifier as a distinguisher instead.

It appears to work with code like this (however I'm wondering if the delegate may get entered before the tag is set):

> SFNetworkOperation *netop = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request
>   delegate:_delegate];
>            netop.tag = @"Test";

Answer (score 2):

Why not use blocks? Blocks make it super easy to enqueue multiple async requests, you'll always know which request has just completed, and they're becoming increasingly commonplace as a good design pattern. (Disclaimer: I contributed the [blocks category](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/native/SalesforceNativeSDK/SalesforceNativeSDK/Classes/SFRestAPI%2BBlocks.h) to the API :)

If you're really set on not using blocks -- why again? -- then you could associate arbitrary data to your `SFRestRequest` with the same runtime functions used by the blocks category.

Another option is to keep a reference to your `SFRestRequest`(s) and, in the completion delegate, determine which request has just completed.

Comment: Great timing, I'm using blocks in some parts of my app but never for this, seems like a much better idea than checking what the query was (which is what I'm doing now!).

Comment: Step back from the edge @LaceySnr! You've too much to live for! For serious though, blocks are invaluable for any async-based work, like dealing with a remote API.

Comment: OK, so I have a DAL class that holds a reference to my SFManager class and also to a CoreDataManager class. I presently have the DAL as the delegate for the SFManager which calls the rest requests. The idea is that the DAL will coordinate keeping CoreData in sync with SF. Now if I start using blocks I guess I could use notifications to let the DAL know, but it seems quite convoluted to do that. Or I could try to pass through a reference to CoreData to the SFManager for use in the blocks, but that feels worse, because it already feels to me like "controller" code should be in the DAL class.

Comment: btw. while I discovered that the code in my question does work under test, I got concerned that maybe the delegate method could possibly get entered even before the tag on SFNetworkOperation got set (is that possible?) So I looked for possible tags on RestRequest and found that AccessibilityValue seemed to work! Feels like a hack though!

Comment: Why overcomplicate things? Just move whatever code is currently in your response delegate into the block itself. Your block can call your DAL.

Comment: Using blocks would be... DAL calls SFManager... SFManager calls rest request... SFManager gets callback to its block... then what.. block calls DAL? So I'd then have the processing of the returned data, saving to CoreData etc living in a file in the middle of the architectural hierarchy. Which isn't so bad because that's where I'd put it anyway, but more importantly the calling code is living in a file (in a block) at the bottom of the hierarchy. I agree with keeping things simple but that's why I have an aversion to it. It feels backwards.

Comment: Also, I do appreciate the blocks API. I like the fact that it has a simple success or fail for example, and the code is right there, where you want to see it. With the advent of huge successes like Node.js, I can see there's something of a trend going on with this kind of style, so I'll take another look at using blocks - thanks.

Comment: I can't say I understand what you mean by `DAL`, but consider a method in your core data manager that takes an array and a completion block as input. Your `SFRestRequest` completion blocks feed it every SOQL result, it processes your core data records asynchronously, then calls your completion block.

Comment: DAL is my "data access layer" - essentially a controller class for all persistence (remote and local) for the app. Its' an interesting idea to pass blocks around, I hadn't considered that. I guess I'm still grappling with the concept of object oriented ownership of behavior when closures/blocks are used. It felt natural to have my DAL to own the "process the callback" behavior, because it has access to both CoreData and Salesforce and can negotiate state between the two. That's why I implemented as delegate.